# SQLAlchemy: AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'foreign_keys' when making association table

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I just set up an association table, so i'm sure there's an error with how I wrote my relationships, but I've been looking over everything for an hour now and can't find it.

my stack trace is telling me the error might have something to do with user join conditions, but i believe i set up the relationships correctly (the migrations ran before with the code written like this):

```
followers_table = Table('users_followers', db.Model.metadata,
                        db.Column('follower_id',
                                  db.Integer,
                                  db.ForeignKey('users.id')),
                        db.Column('following_id',
                                  db.Integer,
                                  db.ForeignKey('users.id')))

awards_table = Table('users_awards', db.Model.metadata,
                     db.Column('user_id',
                               db.Integer,
                               db.ForeignKey('users.id')),
                     db.Column('award_id',
                               db.Integer,
                               db.ForeignKey('awards.id')))
```

and the user model:

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    query = db.session.query_property()

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, unique=True)
    first_name = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    last_name = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    username = db.Column(db.String(40), nullable=False, unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False, unique=True)
    avatar_url = db.Column(db.String)
    bio = db.Column(db.String)
    points_earned = db.Column(db.Integer)
    completed_workouts = db.Column(db.Integer)
    miles_run = db.Column(db.Integer)
    hashed_password = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)
    following = relationship('User', secondary=followers_table,
                             primaryjoin=(
                                 followers_table.c.follower_id == id),
                             secondaryjoin=followers_table.c.following_id == id)
    followers = relationship('User', secondary=followers_table,
                             primaryjoin=(
                                 followers_table.c.following_id == id),
                             secondaryjoin=followers_table.c.follower_id == id)
    awards = relationship('Award', secondary=awards_table,
                          backref="user")
    comment_likes = relationship('Comment', secondary=c_likes,
                                 backref="liked_by")
    post_likes = relationship('User_Post', secondary=p_likes,
                              backref="liked_by")

    @ property
    def password(self):
        return self.hashed_password

    @ password.setter
    def password(self, password):
        self.hashed_password = generate_password_hash(password)

    def check_password(self, password):
        return check_password_hash(self.password, password)

    def to_dict(self):
        return {
            "id": self.id,
            "first_name": self.first_name,
            "last_name": self.last_name,
            "username": self.username,
            "email": self.email,
            "points_earned": self.points_earned,
            "bio": self.bio,
        }

    def to_dict_full(self):
        return {
            "id": self.id,
            "first_name": self.first_name,
            "last_name": self.last_name,
            "username": self.username,
            "email": self.email,
            "avatar_url": self.avatar_url,
            "points_earned": self.points_earned,
            "bio": self.bio,
            "followers": [follower.to_dict() for follower in self.followers],
            "following": [leader.to_dict() for leader in self.following],
            "awards": [award.to_dict() for award in self.awards],
            "posts": [post.to_dict() for post in self.posts],
        }
```

but after I added another association table, everything went haywire:

```
workout_exercises = Table('workout_exercises', db.Model.metadata,
                          db.Column('exercise_id',
                                    db.Integer,
                                    db.ForeignKey('exercises.id')),
                          db.Column('workout_id',
                                    db.Integer,
                                    db.ForeignKey('workouts.id'))),
```

this isn't even referencing the user table, so the error has me confused. i can run the migrations, but when i try to seed the tables is when i get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ryoung7986/00_solo-project/fit-yeah-app/.venv/bin/flask", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/ryoung7986/00_solo-project/fit-yeah-app/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 967, in main
    cli.main(args=sys.argv[1:], prog_name="python -m flask" if as_module else None)
  File "/home/ryoung7986/00_solo-project/fit-yeah-app/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 586, in main
    return super(FlaskGroup, self).main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ryoung7986/00_solo-project/fit-yeah-app/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 782, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/home/ryoung7986/00_solo-project/fit-yeah-app/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1259, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/home/ryoung7986/00_solo-project/fit-yeah-app/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1259, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/home/ryoung7986/00_solo-project/fit-yeah-app/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1066, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/home/ryoung7986/00_solo-project/fit-yeah-app/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 610, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ryoung7986/00_solo-project/fit-yeah-app/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/decorators.py", line 21, in new_func
    return f(get_current_context(), *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ryoung7986/00_solo-project/fit-yeah-app/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 426, in decorator
    return __ctx.invoke(f, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ryoung7986/00_solo-project/fit-yeah-app/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 610, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ryoung7986/00_solo-project/fit-yeah-app/app/seeds/__init__.py", line 21, in seed
    seed_users()
  File "/home/ryoung7986/00_solo-project/fit-yeah-app/app/seeds/users.py", line 9, in seed_users
    demo1 = User(first_name='Demo',
  File "<string>", line 2, in __init__
  File "/home/ryoung7986/00_solo-project/fit-yeah-app/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/instrumentation.py", line 388, in _new_state_if_none
    state = self._state_constructor(instance, self)
  File "/home/ryoung7986/00_solo-project/fit-yeah-app/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 883, in __get__
    obj.__dict__[self.__name__] = result = self.fget(obj)
  File "/home/ryoung7986/00_solo-project/fit-yeah-app/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/instrumentation.py", line 214, in _state_constructor
    self.dispatch.first_init(self, self.class_)
  File "/home/ryoung7986/00_solo-project/fit-yeah-app/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/event/attr.py", line 322, in __call__
    fn(*args, **kw)
  File "/home/ryoung7986/00_solo-project/fit-yeah-app/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/mapper.py", line 3413, in _event_on_first_init
    configure_mappers()
  File "/home/ryoung7986/00_solo-project/fit-yeah-app/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/mapper.py", line 3301, in configure_mappers
    mapper._post_configure_properties()
  File "/home/ryoung7986/00_solo-project/fit-yeah-app/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/mapper.py", line 1966, in _post_configure_properties
    prop.init()
  File "/home/ryoung7986/00_solo-project/fit-yeah-app/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/interfaces.py", line 197, in init
    self.do_init()
  File "/home/ryoung7986/00_solo-project/fit-yeah-app/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/relationships.py", line 2077, in do_init
    self._setup_join_conditions()
  File "/home/ryoung7986/00_solo-project/fit-yeah-app/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/relationships.py", line 2141, in _setup_join_conditions
    self._join_condition = jc = JoinCondition(
  File "/home/ryoung7986/00_solo-project/fit-yeah-app/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/relationships.py", line 2524, in __init__
    self._determine_joins()
  File "/home/ryoung7986/00_solo-project/fit-yeah-app/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/relationships.py", line 2620, in _determine_joins
    self.secondaryjoin = join_condition(
  File "<string>", line 2, in join_condition
  File "<string>", line 2, in _join_condition
  File "/home/ryoung7986/00_solo-project/fit-yeah-app/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/deprecations.py", line 139, in warned
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ryoung7986/00_solo-project/fit-yeah-app/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/selectable.py", line 959, in _join_condition
    constraints = cls._joincond_scan_left_right(
  File "/home/ryoung7986/00_solo-project/fit-yeah-app/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/selectable.py", line 1014, in _joincond_scan_left_right
    b.foreign_keys, key=lambda fk: fk.parent._creation_order
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'foreign_keys'
```

I'm baffled on this one. Hopefully it's a simple typo... thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Of course, it was a typo. Took myself and a few friends to find it. I was defeated by a comma :(

Comment: You helped me! Same thing! Fck comma! Here on fck end of line "serving0 = Serving(name='', grams=1),". One hour spent on this crap.